# Hugo / Blogdown Images Fail to Render After GitHub/Netlify Deployment

Tags: netlify, hugo, blogdown

this is my first time asking a question, so apologies in advance if I do something stupid.

I made my third blogpost with blogdown. I've used images on the first two and everything went well, but this was the first one where the images were created by R code:

```
png_1 <- image_read_pdf("index_files/pdf_with_image_1.pdf")

print(png_1)
```

This created a new folder and the path looks like this:

> \content\post\2021-06-05-mining-text-from-pdf-files-part-3-pdf-with-an-image\index_files\figure-html\

The images themselves are named in this manner: **unnamed-chunk-4-1.png**

After finishing writing the post I made the usual Git/GitHub ritual and Netlify seemed to deploy the post normally.

However, this is what it looks like on the website (image not showing):

[image]

I tried to read about similar problems on GitHub, RStudio Community and even here, but I didn't find a straightforward answer to the problem.

This is what the html code looks like:

```
img src="{{< blogdown/postref >}}index_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-4-1.png" width="1650"
```

I also used blogdown::check_site() to see if there was anything there. At least no [TODO]s there:

```
― Checking config.yaml
| Checking "baseURL" setting for Hugo...
○ Found baseURL = "https://youcanbeapirate.netlify.com/"; nothing to do here!
| Checking "ignoreFiles" setting for Hugo...
○ "ignoreFiles" looks good - nothing to do here!
| Checking setting for Hugo's Markdown renderer...
○ All set! Found the "unsafe" setting for goldmark.
― Check complete: config.yaml

― Checking .gitignore
| Checking for items to remove...
○ Nothing to see here - found no items to remove.
| Checking for items to change...
○ Nothing to see here - found no items to change.
| Checking for items you can safely ignore...
○ Found! You have safely ignored: Thumbs.db, .DS_Store
| Checking for items to ignore if you build the site on Netlify...
○ Found! You have safely ignored: /resources/, /public/
| Checking for files required by blogdown but not committed...
○ Great! Did not find such files.
― Check complete: .gitignore

― Checking Hugo
| Checking Hugo version...
○ Found Hugo. You are using Hugo 0.83.1.
| Checking .Rprofile for Hugo version used by blogdown...
○ blogdown is using Hugo 0.83.1 to build site locally.
― Check complete: Hugo

― Checking netlify.toml...
○ Found HUGO_VERSION = 0.83.1 in [build] context of netlify.toml.
| Checking that Netlify & local Hugo versions match...
○ It's a match! Blogdown and Netlify are using the same Hugo version (0.83.1).
| Checking that Netlify & local Hugo publish directories match...
○ Good to go - blogdown and Netlify are using the same publish directory: public
― Check complete: netlify.toml

― Checking content files
| Checking for validity of YAML metadata in posts...
○ All YAML metadata appears to be syntactically valid.
| Checking for previewed content that will not be published...
○ Found 0 files with future publish dates.
○ Found 0 files marked as drafts.
| Checking your R Markdown content...
○ All R Markdown files have been knitted.
○ All R Markdown output files are up to date with their source files.
| Checking for .html/.md files to clean up...
○ Found 0 duplicate .html output files.
○ Found 0 incompatible .html files to clean up.
| Checking for the unnecessary 'content/' directory in theme...
○ Great! Your theme does not contain the content/ directory.
― Check complete: Content
```

Link to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/AnttiRask/blog)

I can provide more information if needed.

PS: I have presented the same problem on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/hugo-blogdown-images-fail-to-render-after-github-netlify-deployment/106796) as well

Comment: Have you tried `blogdown::check_site()`?

Comment: Thanks, @YihuiXie, I tried that and added the results to the question.

Comment: Great! It seems there is nothing wrong in the results. Then I think we will need to see the source so that we can try to reproduce the problem by ourselves. Do you have a public Github repo for the website project or something like that to share?

Comment: Thanks again @YihuiXie! Added the link to the repo to the question.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, @YihuiXie, but have you been able to reproduce the problem at your end?

Comment: It's on my todo list but I haven't found time yet: https://yihui.org/todo/#todo

Comment: @YihuiXie, I don't know if the two are related, but it does seem to me that by resolving this issue on GitHub, https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/663, you solved the problem I had here.

Comment: Oh really? But I don't see `<!--more-->` in your website source. How did you solve the problem? I don't see new git commits in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

In your most recent post in that repo, I found there is a weird file([https://github.com/AnttiRask/blog/blob/master/content/post/2021-06-05-mining-text-from-pdf-files-part-3-pdf-with-an-image/index.Rmd.lock~](https://github.com/AnttiRask/blog/blob/master/content/post/2021-06-05-mining-text-from-pdf-files-part-3-pdf-with-an-image/index.Rmd.lock%7E)), I guess this might be the reason causing the problem. I quickly tested from my end, it works if I delete that file and re-knit that RMD file.

Comment: Thansk @ifendo for the suggestion. I got rid of that file and made a new pull request to get Netlify to deploy the updated version of the post at the same time I published a new post. 

While I did manage to update the tags that had also been missing, the deletion of the lock-file didn't help with the images.